# SQL Error: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is my SQL query that is throwing a syntax error around/ near the 'FROM' portion. Any help would be awesome!

```
with findlives AS 
(
    select distinct a.ClientId, a.PolicyNo, a.Acc, a.Lives, a.FundTypeCmr 
    from factInforceProfitByFundGb as a 
    where TimePeriodId = 202006 
      and BenefitCode='66' 
      and TerminationDate = '9999-12-31'
)
select sum(Lives) AS spousal 
from findlives 
from [GB_Msi_P1].[dbo].[factInforceProfitByFundGb] as a 
where TimePeriodId >= 201811  
  and BenefitCode in ('25', '26', '29', '46', '66')
group by TimePeriodId
order by TimePeriodId asc
```

Here is the error;

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 22
> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: When you encounter an error and you have a question about the error you should **include that error text with your question**. Don't translate it or paraphrase, copy and paste the complete error text verbatim into the question. Use the [edit] button to update your question with that text.

Comment: You can only have a single `FROM` clause. If you want to join multiple tables you can use `JOIN`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in comments by the-impaler, you can only have one `FROM` clause per `SELECT`. Multiple tables need to be `JOIN`ed together, or (deprecated) chained with commas.

Perhaps you're trying to join the CTE with the table it's based on, but you want type 66 records from the CTE and match them to other type records from the table? In that case you do want a JOIN. Perhaps this one?

```
with findlives AS 
(
    select distinct aaa.ClientId, aaa.PolicyNo, aaa.Acc, aaa.Lives, aaa.FundTypeCmr 
    from factInforceProfitByFundGb as aaa 
    where TimePeriodId = 202006 
      and BenefitCode='66' 
      and TerminationDate = '9999-12-31'
)
select a.TimePeriodId,sum(findlives.Lives) AS spousal 
from findlives 
JOIN [GB_Msi_P1].[dbo].[factInforceProfitByFundGb] as a 
   ON findlives.ClientID=a.clientID
where a.TimePeriodId >= 201811  
  and a.BenefitCode in ('25', '26', '29', '46', '66')
group by a.TimePeriodId
order by a.TimePeriodId asc
```

I've also added additonal table aliases to make things clear, and added `a.TimePeriodId` to the `SELECT` because otherwise your output isn't going to be clear (which output row goes with which group member?)